# ASP.Net MVC Show/Hide Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok I have the following View

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.user>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Password Management";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section title {<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>}

<div id="page-block" class="page-block-three row">

    <div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <div class="input-group">
                @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @class = "form-control ccl-form", @style = "z-index: 10", @placeholder = "Enter Username"})
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn ccl-btn ccl-btn-red ccl-btn-search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="details-block">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                <button type="button" class="btn ccl-btn ccl-btn-green ccl-btn-search pull-right">Select User</button>
            </div>

        }
    </div>

</div>
```

What I want to be able to do is hide the following div

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="details-block">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
                <button type="button" class="btn ccl-btn ccl-btn-green ccl-btn-search pull-right">Select User</button>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
```

Then show that Div when the submit button is clicked

My Controller looks like the following

```
public class PasswordController : Controller
    {
        private CCLPasswordManagementDBEntities db = new CCLPasswordManagementDBEntities();

        public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
        {
            var users = from x in db.users select x;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(x => x.UserName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }

            return View(users);
        }

    }
```

At the moment the div is constantly shown and updates when the submit button is pressed but I want to hide that div until someone presses the submit button then it can show.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: So you want it to show after the form is submitted and the page refreshes (from the form posting)?

Comment: When you submit your rendering a whole new view so the only way you going to do this is with ajax, or by passing additional value(s) to the controller that indicate which items should be shown and render the view according to those value(s)

Comment: Yep I am trying to show this after the for is submitted and refreshes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code in the controller to this:

```
 public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
    {
        var users = from x in db.users select x;
        ViewBag.ShowList = false;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            ViewBag.ShowList = true;
            users = users.Where(x => x.UserName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        }

        return View(users);
    }
```

And change your view to this:

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.user>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Password Management";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section title {<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>}

<div id="page-block" class="page-block-three row">

<div style="margin-top: 30px;" class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="input-group">
            @Html.TextBox("SearchString", null, new { @class = "form-control ccl-form", @style = "z-index: 10", @placeholder = "Enter Username"})
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn ccl-btn ccl-btn-red ccl-btn-search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
@if(ViewBag.ShowList){
<div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="details-block">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            <button type="button" class="btn ccl-btn ccl-btn-green ccl-btn-search pull-right">Select User</button>
        </div>

    }
</div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try having a flag (ViewBag.isShown = false;)

When the page refreshes, it will show your div.

Code should be like below:

> if (ViewBag.isShown == true)
>   {
>       ..your for each block..
>   }